# How to change windows user icon

Tags: windows

At work we setup all our new machines to have a default user. This user has our company logo for it's user picture. I am in the process of automating this, and am having a hard time finding a way to change a users picture without manually setting it up. Is this possible, and if so, how may I do it? This needs to work for  Windows 7, but support for other versions is a plus.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about simply creating a disk image of the HDD of one of the machines and copy it to all other machines? Or is this not possible with Windows? Assuming all machines are identical.

Comment: Unfortunately not all machines are identical (far from it). To further complicate things, not all machines have the same tools to be installed, even if they were identical hardware.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer (for Windows 7 at least) over at: http://joco.name/2010/12/06/i-discovered-the-new-windows-user-tile-api/

The little example application given works great.

Comment: Since you solved the problem yourself, please mark your answer as accepted to get this question off the list of open questions.

Comment: @Ben Voigt, am I missing something? I tried to do that 2 hours ago, but it says that I have to wait 2 days.

Comment: No, you really do have to wait a while before accepting your *own* answer. You can accept someone posted by someone else much more quickly. It's no big deal; just accept it whenever you can. Nice find, by the way.